# post json data to php and echo result

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, post

I'm a struggling learner of php and javascript and Have been searching frantically for a solutionbut to no avail. I am trying to send a json object/string from one page to another using php and then echo the results in that new page (eventually to generate a pdf using tcppdf) . So basically some javascript generates an object, `pageStructure`, in one page, which I then stringify:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(pageStructure);
alert(jsonString);`
```

The alert pops up fine.

I now want to send (post) this to another php file `getdata.php` and then play around with it to construct a pdf.

I have tried posting with forms but updating the value of an input in the form with `jsonString` won't work.

**ADDITION - EXPLANATION OF MY PROBLEM HERE
I created a form as follows:

```
<form action="getdata.php" method="post">
  <textarea type="hidden" id="printMatter" name="printMatter" value=""></textarea>          
  <button type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" ></span></button>
</form>
```

I have some code after constructing `jsonString` to set the value of the `textarea` to that value:

```
document.getElementById('printMatter').value = jsonString;
alert(document.getElementById('printMatter').value);
```

A submit button activates the form which opens the getdata.php page but I noticed two things:

(1) before sending the jsonString string is full of escapes () before every quote mark (").

(2) when getdata.php opens, the echoed jsonString has changed to include no \s but instead one of the values ('value') of an object in the json string (a piece of svg code including numerous \s) - for example (truncated because the value is a very long svg string, but this gives the idea):

```
{"type":"chartSVG","value":"<g transform=\"translate(168.33333333333334,75)\" class=\"arc\">...
```

has changed to integers - for example:

```
{"type":"chartSVG","value":"12"}
```

I don't understand how or why this happens and what to do to get the full svg code to be maintained after the form is posted.

**

I have tried using jquery/ajax as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'getdata.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: {printMatter: jsonString},
  success: function(){
    alert('it worked');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('it failed')}
})
```

I'm getting the success response but I end up on the same page instead of getting the new php file to just echo what it is being sent!

The php script contains the following:

```
<?php
  echo $_POST['printMatter'];
?>
```

But this doesn't work. Nor does trying to add a header to the php page (e.g. `header('Content: application/json')`. I end up staying on my original page. How do I get this to leave me on the new page (getdata.php) with an echo of the json string?

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong or how I can get what I want?

Thank you so much.

**ADDITION
This is indicative of how I get the `jsonString` object:

```
 function item(type,value) {
  this.type = type;
  this.value = value;
 }

for (i=0;i<thePage[0].length;i++) {
  pageid = thePage[0][i].id;
  var entry = new item("page",pageid);
  pageStructure.push(entry);
}

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(pageStructure);
```

So I end up with a series of pages listed out in the `jsonString`.

Comment: If you actually want to "go" to `getdata.php` instead of just posting to it (which is what I get from your question of "How do I get this to leave me on the new page (getdata.php)..."), then you probably want a regular form post instead of ajax. You might want to change this question to be about how to get that to work. Since you say that you tried and it didn't work, show what you tried and explain what went wrong.

Comment: you are sending data by get request but at php you receiving as post method.make both same.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes - thanks for pointing this out, I should have explained it. I've now added a section showing where I got stuck with this (just tried something new and it seems to be getting closer - but a new obstacle cropped up!). Thanks for your advice.

Comment: It has to use backslaches because that is the escape character and you have `"` in your string which need to be escaped. Otherwise the JSON will be invalid and not decode properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing $_POST to $_GET since your AJAX request is doing a HTTP GET and not a HTTP POST.

Comment: Thanks, i meant this to use post! This doesn't solve my problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You are using AJAX. By nature AJAX will not refresh the page for example if you do this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'getdata.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: {printMatter: jsonString},
  success: function(data){
    alert('it worked');
    alert('You sent this json string: ' + data);
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('it failed')}
});
```

Also note that I changed your `type` from `'get'` to `'post'`... The type set here will in part determine where you can access the data you are sending... if you set it to get then in getdata.php you need to use `$_GET`, if you set it to `post` then you should use `$_POST`.

Now if you actually want a full page refresh as you implied then you would need to do this another way. How you would go about it i cant say because you haven't provided enough  of an idea of what happens to get your `jsonString` before sending it.

### Update

> This doesn't leave me on the page I want to be on. I don't want to refresh the page but just redirect to a new page that receives the posted json data.

By this is essentially a page "refresh", though perhaps "refresh mislead you because it can imply reloading the current URL. What I meant by refresh was a completely new page load. Which is essentially what you are asking for. There are a few ways to go about this...

If you data is pretty short and will not violate the maximum length for a URI on the webserver then you can just use `window.location`:

```
// send it as json like you are currently trying to do
window.location = 'getdata.php?printMatter=' + encodeURIComponent(jsonString);

// OR send it with typical url-encoded data and dont use JSON
window.location = 'getdata.php?' + $.serialize(pageStructure);
```

In this case you would use `$_GET['printMatter']` to access the data as opposed to `$_POST['printMatter']`.

If the data has the potential to produce a long string then you will need to POST it. This gets a bit trickier since if we want to POST we have to use a form. Using JSON and jQuery that is pretty simple:

```
var form = '<form action="getdata.php" method="post">'
           +    '<input type="hidden" name="printMatter" value="%value%" />'
           + '</form>';

form.replace('$value%', jsonString);

// if you have any visual styles on form that might then you may 
// need to also position this off screen with something like 
// left: -2000em or what have you
$(form).css({position: 'absolute'}) 
  .appendTo('body')
  .submit();
```

If we wanted to just send this as normal formdata then it would get more complex because we would need to recursively loop over `pageStructure` and create input elements with the proper `name` attribute... I wouldn't go that route.

So the final way (but I don't think it would work because it seems like you're trying to generate a file and have the browser download it) would be to send it over AJAX and have ajax return the next url to go to:

JS

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'getdata.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: {printMatter: jsonString},
  type: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    window.location = data.redirectUrl;
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('it failed')}
});
```

getdata.php

```
// do something with the $_POST['printMatter'] data and then...

$response = array(
  'redirectUrl' =>$theUrlToGoTo
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
print json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have corrected the get/post issue. This doesn't leave me on the page I want to be on. I don't want to refresh the page but just redirect to a new page that receives the posted json data.

Comment: @AndreLing see my update... not sure if thats what you want because you still arent being terribly clear, but i think i get what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I do have a very long string (including large chunks of svg code). I managed to get the form to post the data but when I try to echo it in php, I find that part of it has been pasted as text and part of it has been pasted as html. This seems to explain the phenomena I observed of value being changed from svg strings into numbers. Now I'm unable to get the jsonString to just print the full json text, without some of it turning into html (not visible because its fragments of svg) on the php page. :( Any further advice would be very gratefully received.